# Integrating reciprocal of the square of two numbers

Tags: calculus

How do I integrate the reciprocal of the square of 2 numbers? Take an example.. $$\int\frac {dv}{a/b+v^2} $$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are positive, write $r=\sqrt(a/b)$, so that your integral becomes $\int \frac{dv}{r^2 + v^2}$. Then substitute $v= sinh(t)$.

Comment: If you mean $\int \frac{dv}{(a/b)+v^2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants, there are $3$ cases: (1) $\frac{a}{b}\gt 0$; (2) $\lt 0$; (3) $=0$.

Comment: @Andrew : Could you write $\sqrt{a/b}$ rather than $\sqrt(a/b)$ and $\sinh(t)$ or $\sinh t$ rather than $sinh(t)$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't see how this can be described as "the reciprocal of the square of two numbers". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a,b>0$ (or $a,b<0$, in which case we replace $a$ and $b$ by $|a|$ and $|b|$, respectively).  Consider
$$
\int\frac{dv}{a/b+v^2}
$$
We can factor the denominator as
$$
\int\frac{dv}{a/b+v^2}=\int\frac{dv}{a/b(1+(\sqrt{b}v/\sqrt{a})^2)}=\frac{b}{a}\int\frac{dv}{1+(\sqrt{b}v/\sqrt{a})^2}.
$$
Let $u=\sqrt{b}v/\sqrt{a}$ so that $du=\sqrt{b}dv/\sqrt{a}$ or that $dv=\sqrt{a}du/\sqrt{b}$.  Then, 
$$
\frac{b}{a}\int\frac{dv}{1+(\sqrt{b}v/\sqrt{a})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}v}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+C
$$

In the case where $b/a<0$, a similar computation works by factoring out $-|b|/|a|=b/a$ and using $\text{arctanh}$.

In the case where $b/a=0$, the integral is an elementary integral.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$, then $\int\frac {dv}{a/b+v^2}=\int\frac {dv}{v^2}=-\frac{-1}{v}+C$

If $\frac{a}{b}>0$, it's an $\arctan $ form:

$\int\frac {dv}{a/b+v^2}=\int\frac {dv}{(\sqrt \frac{a}{b})^{2}+v^2}=\sqrt \frac{b}{a}\tan ^{-1}\left ( \sqrt \frac{b}{a} \right )v+C$

If $\frac{a}{b}<0$, set $r^{2}=\vert \frac{a}{b}\vert $ and use partial fractions:

$\int\frac {dv}{v^2-r^{2}}={-\dfrac{\ln\left(x+r\right)-\ln\left(x-r\right)}{2r}}+C$. Now backsubstitute for $r$.